# kubectl error: error loading config file "/var/lib/jenkins/.kube/config":

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-deployment, kubectl

I am configuring Jenkins to automatically deploy my successfull builds to my Kubernetes cluster. I have manually set up the `KUBECONFIG` file in `/var/lib/jenkins/.kube/config`.

But my Jenkins job keeps giving the same error:

```
+ kubectl config --kubeconfig=/var/lib/jenkins/.kube/config view
error: error loading config file "/var/lib/jenkins/.kube/config": v1.Config.Contexts: \
[]v1.NamedContext: Clusters: []v1.NamedCluster: v1.NamedCluster.Name: Cluster: v1.Cluster.Server: \
CertificateAuthorityData: decode base64: illegal base64 data at input byte 47, error found in #10 byte of ... \
|ASXY9gkN$","server":|..., bigger context ...|"LS3tGS1PR0dJTiBDRVJUMLPAR0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUV5gkN$", \
"server":"https://clsx-cloud-d734ef-0b|...
```

I copied the kube config file manually from my SSH accessible account, i.e

```
cat home/username/.kube/config
```

Comment: Where does Jenkins running ? inside the same cluster? or outside?

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI No, I have Jenkins running on a seperate Azure VM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely copied the wrong screen output from the terminal, or while editing the file in i.e `nano`.

The `$` characters are illegal characters and the result of truncated file viewing in the terminal, make sure that you copy the real file data correctly.

For example:

```
xclip -sel clip < home/username/.kube/config
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this error by removing files in this directory:

`/var/lib/jenkins/.kube/`

*Note*: take backup on first priority of this directory as well.